# Getting feature count of QgsVectorLayer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, count

I'm using this code to get features from QgsVectorLayer

```
 QgsVectorDataProvider* provider=theVectorLayer->dataProvider();
            if(!provider)
            {
                return;
            }

            theVectorLayer->select(provider->attributeIndexes(),theVectorLayer->extent(),true,false);
    theVectorLayer->selectedFeatureCount();//here returns 0 but there is one polygon
    while(theVectorLayer->nextFeature(currentFeature))
            {
         ....//here Iget attributes and current geometry (one polygon)
            }
```

How do I get feature count?

Method featureCount() returns -1.

Comment: I suggest you check its source, -1 sounds like it encountered an error and then intentionally returned an invalid result.

Comment: Why method selectedFeatureCount returns 0?

Comment: The obvious answer would be that the previous select call didn't select anything. Check your parameters.

Comment: In while I get one feature with polygon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When [featureCount()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a65286a9f1c393269cc392fbe539b37b0) returns -1 the only safe bet to get the feature count is to iterate over all feature and count them.

[selectedFeatureCount()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a28fc35e5b3231b2069bd6d0a181949af) is the number of features that are selected on the layer (e.g. with [setSelectedFeatures()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a4d82285142c108ba73622ce53207759c) or [void select(QgsFeatureId featureId, bool emitSignal=true)](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#aa2e43a92fd5c2f4f9870c35cf37af409)), but has nothing to do with the [select()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a13c6551c0b96da88004904d584599185)/[nextFeature()](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a084f8ed91fb514b7424617f08ce3bd86) combo.