# Getting total feature count for multiple layers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.18, feature-count

I want the total feature count of all the features in all my layers. Doing it manually in QGIS 2.18.16 is too slow.

I have been trying PyQGIS, but am not good with PyQGIS.

Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

List the vector layers and sum their feature counts:

```
sum([l.featureCount() for l in iface.mapCanvas().layers() if l.type()==QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer])
```

[image]

See [PyQGIS: How to get the list of valid layers in TOC?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150611/pyqgis-how-to-get-the-list-of-valid-layers-in-toc) and [How do I get feature count of a QgsVectorLayer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29500/how-do-i-get-feature-count-of-a-qgsvectorlayer)